# Gsub the first to digits of a date

Tags: r, function, replace, gsub

I want to reshape a year '1984' into '84' in my dataset. I just want to remove the first to digits ('19') and ('20') so only the last two numbers will remain.

I've tried the following:

```
gsub('19+', '', year)
gsub('20+', '', year)
```

These codes also delete the years 1919 or 2020 completely but that's not the idea.

What code can I try while using gsub?

Comment: You probably just need `states$Year <- substring(states$Year, 3)` unless you have years from the centuries other than 20 and 21.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `19+` will match a 1 followed by 1 or more times a 9. Using `20+` will match a 2 followed by 1 or more times a zero. As gsub replaces all matches of a string, you will match both 1919 and 2020, as it will alse for example 19999919 or 200.

---

You might use a pattern to match either 19 or 20 and capture the last 2 digits in a capture group.

In the replacement use the first capture group using `\\1`, and use word boundaries `\b` around the pattern to prevent the digits being part of a larger string.

```
gsub('\\b(?:19|20)(\\d\\d)\\b', '\\1', "1984")
```

Output

```
[1] "84"
```

[R demo](https://ideone.com/Zctofa)

A broader match could be matching 2 digits at the start instead of 19 or 20.

```
gsub('\\b\\d{2}(\\d{2})\\b', '\\1', "1984")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `^` for beginning of string.

```
gsub("^19|^20", "", year)
# [1] "19" "28" "37" "46" "55" "64" "73" "82" "91" "00" "09" "18"
```

Alternatively using `substring`.

```
substring(year, 3)
# [1] "19" "28" "37" "46" "55" "64" "73" "82" "91" "00" "09" "18"
```

---

*Data:*

```
year <- seq(1919, 2021, 9)
```